# SQL REPLACE with Multiple [0-9]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have a string that I want to replace a group of numbers.
The string contains groupings of numbers (and a few letters).  'A12 456 1 65 7944'
I want to replace the group of 3 numbers with 'xxx', and the group of 4 numbers with 'zzzz'

I thought something like `REPLACE(@str, '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 'xxx')` would work, but it doesn't.  I can't even get `'%[0-9]%'` to replace anything.

If REPLACE is not suitable, how can I replace groups of numbers?

Comment: @DaleK Suggestions on how to accomplish this without REPLACE?

Comment: Not really, its not something SQL is good at... if you have to do it in SQL Server try a CLR function.

Comment: I think I can use PATINDEX and STUFF

Comment: To easily do this, you need a regex replacement, which sadly SQL Server does not support out of the box.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I'm using Azure which is running SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution based on XML and XQuery.

Notable points:

1. We are tokenizing input string as XML in the `CROSS APPLY` clause.
2. XQuery's FLWOR expression is checking for numeric integer values with
   a particular length, and substitutes then with a replacement string.
3. XQuery `.value()` method outputs back a final result.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('A12 456 1 65 7944');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.* 
    , c.query('
    for $x in /root/r/text()
    return if (xs:int($x) instance of xs:int and string-length($x)=3) then "xxx"
        else if (xs:int($x) instance of xs:int and string-length($x)=4) then "zzzz"
        else data($x)
    ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| ID |      tokens       |      Result       |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | A12 456 1 65 7944 | A12 xxx 1 65 zzzz |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Now that's pretty slick.  How's it for performance?

Comment: XQuery is a hidden gem in MS SQL Server. I hope the OP will try the proposed solution, and report the outcome, including performance.

Comment: Have you got a good reference or references on how to use XQuery?  I normally dislike it because of what people do with it and the performance is actually terrible the way most people use it.  I thought your solution was quite clever and I'm going to do some performance tests with your good code.  If it works out, you may have converted me a bit.

Comment: Here is a good free XQuery training: https://www.altova.com/training/xquery3

Comment: @JeffModen, I recently sent you few messages in LinkedIn.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll take a look.